# How to debug in production envirnment for ASP.NET web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Our client recently complains that when they work on our production server, the user menu switch randomly, but this happens only occasionally .

The application has two types of user menu: regular user and restricted user. The target browser is IE. It's a ASP.NET3.5 application written in C#.

We can never reproduce this issue in our local environment. So it is very difficult to debug it.

Anybody met this type of issue or any clue how to debug it?

Answer (score 3):

**Web App Logging**

Have you looked into adding a variable to your web.config  to have your application perfrom less or more logging. I've done this in the past to track down bugs.

**Client-side Logging**

Perhaps not the intended use, but http://www.clicktale.com/ provides a javascript site analytics tools that can record all user mouse/keyboard activity that you could correlate to the web app logs. However it cost $$$.

Answer (score 2):

Log Messages.  Log them all over that has anything to do with the menu.  Then the next time the user reports seeing it look at the log message.

Answer (score 0):

Does the production environment use any load balancing s/w? Perhaps there is a problem with some session scope variables.